# Importing Lahman Baseball Database into Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm a new user to MySQL and MySQL workbench 6.3, and I am attempting to run the SQL script to open the Lahman baseball database 2015 SQL version. Link below:

http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/

I have unzipped the file and I have been able to run the script file 'stats', but I keep getting an error message when I try to run the larger file 'mssqlmaster'.  I go to the open a SQL script in a new query tab and get the warning that it is a large file.  I have then tried the run SQL script option with the default schema Name set to bbdata and the default character set left blank.

I then get this error code:

> Preparing...
>   Importing mssqlmaster.sql...
>   ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: '��U'.
>   Finished executing script
>   Operation failed with exitcode 1

I have tried changing the default character set but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "mssqlmaster" looks like you got the wrong dump. This is for M$ sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mssqlmaster.sql file in the core/ directory is obviously for MS SQL server and not for MySQL. The stats.sql file is a MySQL dump and can directly be imported into MySQL. If you think that stats.sql does not contain as many records as the MS SQL variant then try the CSV download and import that instead (see LOAD DATA command in MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles on this, I've built a script for building a MySQL version of the latest Lahman data. It is available at https://github.com/WebucatorTraining/lahman-baseball-mysql.

Download lahman-mysql-dump.sql and import it into MySQL using MySQL Workbench:

1. Server > Data Import
2. Select Import from Self-Contained File
3. Pick any Default Target Schema. It will be ignored, as the file creates a new one.
4. Click Start Import button.